# HttpUrlConnection Reset Request Properties

Tags: java, urlconnection

I have the code which sets a request property of a custom range of bytes to read from. Is it possible to reset the range back to normal, like clear the range. The code is:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + startByteIdx + "-" + endStr);
```

Is there a way to reset the range to read from the start again?

Answer (score 0):

Why? You can't reuse an HttpURLConnection. You will get a new one next time you connect the URL.